# Shifting down a UITextView from storyboard programmatically within a tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitextview, tableview

I have tried so many different solutions, but nothing seems to move the UITextView from storyboard down programmatically when I need it to.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";
        Celleventmain *cellz = (Celleventmain *)[tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

....
 CGRect schedulesNewFrame = CGRectMake(cellz.labe.frame.origin.x,
                                              cellz.labe.frame.origin.y + 200,
                                              cellz.labe.frame.size.width,
                                              cellz.labe.contentSize.height);

        [cellz.labe setFrame: schedulesNewFrame];
    return cellz;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to be very careful with this code if you get it working - you're altering the frame of the UITextView for the cell. For tablecells, they get reused. This means that as you scroll down, the first cell that was popped off will be reused. It's origin.y is already +200, so now it'll be +400 since you're shifting the y by +200 again. If you do this you need to have a way to reset the frame

Answer (score 1):

You just just use constraints to solve this. Place the UITextView in the UITableViewCell.contentView. and place a top spacing constraint between the textView and the tableviewcell with 200 units (or whatever you need it to be).

You may also need to turn off translatesAutosizingMaskIntoConstraints on the contentView of your Celleventmain.